# Improper formatting while using threading and queues

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, formatting, queue

The code I wrote below is supposed to output something along the lines of this:

```
<Floor(Thread-3, started 44660)> <Bank(Thread-1, started 43356)> shutting down
<Floor(Thread-4, started 44108)> received a message: shutting down (0, 'UP')
<Bank(Thread-1, started 43356)> received a message: (1, 'DOWN')
<Bank(Thread-1, started 43356)> shutting down
<Bank(Thread-2, started 27800)> shutting down
```

However, the formatting of the output seems inconsistent at times. For example:

```
<Floor(Thread-3, started 27076)> <Bank(Thread-1, started 44608)>shutting down
<Floor(Thread-4, started 28772)>received a message:  (shutting down0, 'UP')

<Bank(Thread-1, started 44608)> received a message: (1, 'DOWN')
<Bank(Thread-1, started 44608)> shutting down
<Bank(Thread-2, started 41480)> shutting down
```

Consistent data is important in most programs. Why is this output inconsistent and how do I prevent it?

```
import threading
import Queue

banks = []
floors = []

class Bank(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mailbox = Queue.Queue()
        banks.append(self.mailbox)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.mailbox.get()
            if data == 'shutdown':
                print self, 'shutting down'
                return
            print self, 'received a message:', data

    def stop(self):
        banks.remove(self.mailbox)
        self.mailbox.put('shutdown')
        self.join()

class Floor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, number = 0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mailbox = Queue.Queue()
        floors.append(self.mailbox)
        self.number = number

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.mailbox.get()
            if data == 'shutdown':
                print self, 'shutting down'
                return
            print self, 'received a message:', data

    def stop(self):
        floors.remove(self.mailbox)
        self.mailbox.put('shutdown')
        self.join()

    def call(self, data):
        banks[0].put((self.number, data))

b0 = Bank()
b1 = Bank()
b0.start()
b1.start()
f0 = Floor(0)
f1 = Floor(1)
f0.start()
f1.start()
f0.call('UP')
f1.call('DOWN')
f0.stop()
f1.stop()
b0.stop()
b1.stop()
```

Comment: By 'inconsistent' did you really mean only an extra newline or was the output more interleaved than that?

Comment: @Andy Whitespaces and newlines are expendable (but I wonder why those are inconsistent as well). The most intriguing part is `(shutting down0, 'UP')`. Somehow those messages get concatenated every once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, since your `call()` calls are now being executed in distinct threads, there is nothing that guarantees that they will execute (and output) synchronously.  If you want to guarantee that the output is not interleaved, you'll need to place a large global lock (mutex) around your print calls.

Even this won't guarantee that they are ordered consistently - for example different lines above can easily be switched - in which case you'll need to lock chain your calls.  Incidentally, this will negate almost any performance advantage of multithreading this in the first place.

Comment: I assumed stdout would be claimed by one and after it's finished by the other. The order of execution is irrelevant, but interleaving is problematic. So I got my design all wrong?

Comment: `print` is not thread safe...  But even if it was, that would only solve the interleaving between lines problem.  Lines themselves can still be switched.  So yeah, if you want synchronous output, you need a synchronous design - threads are asynchronous beasts.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is not thread safe. However, `sys.stdout.write` is.

This does solve the immediate problem of interleaving, but I doubt it's the most proper way.